# create a dataframe in python from variable size lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple lists like following

```
a = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(3, 4)]
b = [("foo", "bar")]
c = [(4938,1203), (329,213)]
```

I want to convert this to data frame like following

```
a       b      c
(1,1)  ("foo","bar")  (4938,1203)
(2,2)   NA            (329,213)
(3,3)  NA              NA
(3,4)   NA              NA
```

Comment: Like `pd.DataFrame([a,b,c], index=list('abc')).T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series(a), 'b': pd.Series(b), 'c': pd.Series(c)})
```

This then will yield:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series(a), 'b': pd.Series(b), 'c': pd.Series(c)})
>>> df
        a           b             c
0  (1, 1)  (foo, bar)  (4938, 1203)
1  (2, 2)         NaN    (329, 213)
2  (3, 3)         NaN           NaN
3  (3, 4)         NaN           NaN
```